# Not able to access local network websites using Android’s browsers

Tags: android, firewall

I’m running an Ubuntu web server on my local network, hosting websites that can be accessed anywhere on the network using https, such as  https://ubuntu-server/website01/index.php

However, I cannot access such websites on the browsers of my Android phone that is connected via Wi-Fi.  I have tried using the IP address instead of the domain name, ect.  The phone is able to connect to external websites.  Surprisingly I have not found information about this that has worked.  Also the local sites are able to be accessed by default on iOS but not Android.

Is it some sort of a firewall issue in the Android phone?  If so, where I do set that using the default software?

I see a lot of options for adding third party firewall software to Android, would I need to go that route instead?  I would like to know how to do it by default anyway if possible, however.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Probably off topic here. See: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230643/3573 from the comment look for and disable 'Private DNS' https://support.google.com/android/answer/9654714?hl=en#zippy=%2Cprivate-dns

Comment: Is your phone on cellular or wifi?  If cellular it won't work unless you have a public IP.  If wifi then make sure your router is configured correctly to allow your device to hit the server.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan, router only has to be configured if client uses a mobile connection. With wifi nothing has to be done.

Comment: @blackapps Not true at all.  Every router I've ever had has a NAT built into it which needs a hole poked in it.  Otherwise it won't allow traffic through to random ports

Comment: @Gabe Sechan, well i have never ever done something to a router to let lan/wifi clients communicate with each other. Also when an Android device is used as a hotspot the clients of it can communicate with each other without any configuration.

Comment: @blackapps Then you have weird routers.  I've never had one that allowed incoming connections to any device without poking a hole in the NAT-  especially not a wireless router.  Also, the "I can't contact my device on my WLAN" question gets asked here daily, and the answer is always "you need to poke a hole in the NAT".

Comment: @Gabe Sechan, Local lan-wifi traffic is no incoming connection. A mobile client using the public ip of your router is an incoming connection for your router. And for that you have to do port forwarding. But for local lan-wifi traffic you have to do nothing. Never used an Android device as hotspot?

Comment: @blackapps Local traffic is still an incoming connection to that device.  I have never owned a router that allows that by default.  You always end up needing to poke a hole.  I had to poke one just yesterday, on my bog standard Verizon router.  You're justy wrong here.

Comment: Then use an Android device as hotspot and let all your pc's and other Android devices connect to it. They just can communicate. (The Android device that offers the hotspot does not need a simcard).